# "Bisnieto" o "biznieto", ¿cuál fue antes?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, sustantivos, parentesco

Hoy he leído en un sitio la palabra "[biznieto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dzpJJg)", que me ha sonado un tanto rara porque yo estoy acostumbrado a "[bisnieto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bwRHIo)". Actualmente en el DLE vienen las dos recogidas, aunque la versión con "z" redirige a la versión con "s", lo que supongo indica que esta última variante es la más común.

Sin embargo, históricamente ¿cuál fue antes? ¿Qué versión sería la más fiel al étimo original? ¿Y cómo se originó la otra?

Comment: En los diccionarios, **Bisnieto** aparece ya en el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495 - curiosamente no en el Diccionario de Autoridades, donde aparece bi**z**nieto (El hijo, ò hija de nuestros nietos. Es voz compuesta del Latino Bis, que vale dos veces, y del nombre Nieto, por cuya razón se debiéra decir Bisniéto; pero el uso común ha mudado la s en z.) (Parece otro caso similar al de recoger **Oy** en vez de **Hoy**).  **Biznieto** aparece por primera vez en el de Minsheu (1617), en el que remite a **bisnieto**

Comment: @Leonardo tu comentario es lo suficientemente bueno como para constituir una respuesta, ¡anímate a escribirla!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Fundéu dice esto:

> [**bisnieto/biznieto:**](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/bisnietobiznieto-1509/)
>
> Mi consulta se refiere a si es verdad que cuando la RAE sancionó la palabra «biznieto» o «bizcocho» cometió un error (o fue una fe de errata) al meter esa 'zeta' en vez de una 'ese'; pero que luego corrigió pero ya el daño estaba hecho, por ello dice que ambas grafías están correctas. ¿Qué hay de cierto?
>
> > Cuando la Academia preparó su primer diccionario, las dos formas de «bisnieto»/«biznieto» ya gozaban de amplio uso, aunque solo incluyó la forma con «z»; no incorporó la forma con «s» hasta el siglo XIX. En la práctica, ambas formas han coexistido desde antiguo, incluso después de este primer diccionario, por lo que no hay daño alguno.
> >
> > Las razones por las que prefirió la forma con «z» están explicadas en esa primera edición: entonces pensaban que, de las dos formas existentes, esa era la más extendida (lo que excluye que se trate de una errata). El caso de «bizcocho» seguramente es similar, aunque la forma con «s» claramente ha desaparecido.

Etimologicamente, la forma 'autentica' es *bisnieto* del latín *bis* + *nepta*. La *s* queda en otras palabras similares:

- *bisnieto, **biznieto*** `esp`, *bisñetu, bisnietu, **bizñetu, biznietu*** `ast`, *bisneto* `gal/pt`, *besnét* `cat`
- *bisavô* `pt`, *bisavó* `gal`, *bisabuelo* `esp`, *bisgüelu, bisbuelu, bisagüelu, bisabuelu* `ast`, *besàvia* `cat`, *bisaïeul* `fr`, *bisavolo, bisavo* `it`
- *bisnonno* `it`, [*bisnono*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/bisnono) `vec/`[`tal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talian_dialect)`/pt (Br.)`
- *besnebot* `cat`, *bisnipote* `it`
- *besoncle, bestia* `cat`
- *bessons* `cat`

La confusión entre *s* y *z* también ha ocurrido en otras palabras españolas:

- `lat` *versicāre → [bizquear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dGU5by)
- `lat` *versĭcus → [bizco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dKjjpZ)
- `lat` bissaccia → [bizaza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dCYvve)
- `lat` biscoctus → [bizcocho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dSFlW4)
- `esp` bisbirindo → [bizbirindo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dG9dm6)
- `it` biscottella → [bizcotela](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dghhBQ)
- `ar` *bis[s]ináqa → [biznaga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dv2DUv|5dvHYp3)